# How to select cols dynamically ? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select col according to an col value :

```
$query = SELECT col1,col3,col4 if col5>1 , SELECT col2,col3 if col5<1 
         FROM table1 WHERE id='745';
```

How to do that ?

Comment: Thats not a set,put the condition in the WHERE clause.

Comment: If you need to dynamically select the columns, then you'd have to use dynamic SQL - you cannot do this in a typically select statement.

Comment: can you explain what you want in human language (as opposed to pseudo code). also posting sample data and expected result will help to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you want, but it works for me:

```
SELECT IF(col5 < 1, col1, col2), col3, IF(col5 < 1, col4,"") 
  FROM table1 where id = '745';
```

Comment: The `$query =` part doesn't make any sense unless that's all inside quotes. Posting just the SQL without the scripting around it is probably the best way to present this.

Comment: @tadman Correct, I had quickly tried it out in my envt - without the `$query1`... edited the answer, thanks for the heads up.